# Setting TensorFlow on Mac with PyCharm

Tags: python, macos, intellij-idea, tensorflow, pycharm

I have installed Python3 and TensorFlow 1.0 on my Mac and it works fine when I run code in "terminal" with command line.

```
$ python3 /Users/yeongsanggim/git/pythonstudy/study/tf01.py
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.8.0.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.5.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.8.0.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.1.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.8.0.dylib locally
```

But when I use IntelliJ or PyCharm  and run the same code,

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 /Users/yeongsanggim/git/pythonstudy/study/tf01.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/yeongsanggim/git/pythonstudy/study/tf01.py", line 1, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See     https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why is this happening???
How can I fix this?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398672/pycharm-remote-interpreter-and-tensorflow-can-not-import-cudart-so) may be of interest

Answer (score 2):

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib
```

Choose "Edit Configuration". You will see an Environment option where you need to click on the ... box and enter the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH that applies to your case.

Note that there's an Environment option for the specific file you're working on (it will be highlighted in the left panel) and for Defaults (put DYLD_... there as well if you want future files you create to have this). Note that you need to save this config or else when you close PyCharm it won't stick.